# Load excel worksheet to netezza

Tags: excel, netezza

I would like to load an excel worksheet stored on my Desktop to Netezza. How can I do this without going through the import tool. So I want to be able to write an `INSERT INTO` script that does this.

Here's what I have:

```
INSERT INTO MyNetezzaTable
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\book1.xlsx'
USING
(
Y2BASE 2000
REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
SKIPROWS 1
MAXERRORS 1
ENCODING 'internal'
)
```

In my `nzbad` file, there's a line with a bunch of gibberish characters. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Do a file->save as->CSV 
And then netezza loader can read it fine.
Native xlsx format is binary and cannot be handled without some hassle (actually it’s a ZIP containing several files in xml and jpg and much else)